# Passing variables from login form

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm trying to pass two variables from a login form.Not sure is it the right way. My login form and main one created on QstackedWidget. However, as result I'm getting an empty list. Where is my mistake? Code below:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.central_widget = QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.start_screen = Start(self)
        self.second_screen = Second(self)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(self.start_screen)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(self.second_screen)
        self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.start_screen)
        self.start_screen.clicked.connect(lambda:   self.myshort(self.second_screen))
        self.second_screen.clicked.connect(lambda:  self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.start_screen))

    def myshort(self, your_function):
        print(self.my_notes[0], self.my_notes[1]) #empty list
        return self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(your_function)

class Start(QWidget):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Start, self).__init__(parent)
        self.textName = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textPass = QLineEdit(self)
        self.buttonSave = QPushButton('Save Details', self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.textName)
        layout.addWidget(self.textPass)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonSave)
        self.buttonSave.clicked.connect(self.my_notes())

    def my_notes(self):
        MainWindow.my_notes = []
        MainWindow.my_notes.append(str(self.textName.text()))
        MainWindow.my_notes.append(str(self.textPass.text()))
        return self.clicked.emit


class Second(QWidget):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Second, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        button = QPushButton(text=QString('Back to Start!'))
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        button.clicked.connect(self.clicked.emit)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
myWindow = MainWindow(None)
myWindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

in `class Start`, method `__init__`

```
self.buttonSave.clicked.connect(self.my_notes())
```

remove bracelets:

```
self.buttonSave.clicked.connect(self.my_notes)
```

and in `class Start`, method `my_notes` change:

```
return self.clicked.emit
```

to:

```
self.clicked.emit()
```